# Accessing light bulbs on ceiling fan

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

We just bought a house and it has this ceiling fan:

[image]

The upper portion has bulbs in it, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how you'd get to them. The top of the unit has a metal plate secured with 6 or 8 screws. I can believe you'd have to remove all of those screws, especially so close to the ceiling, to change the bulbs. The plastic side pieces do not seem to come out. Anyone have a fan like this and know how to access the bulbs?

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious just to be thorough-- is it not possible to reach your hand down into the opening at the top of the globe and simply unscrew them?

Comment: No the openings a very small, just to let the light out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That maybe your only way, so you may have to use a stubby screwdriver. Who is the manufacture and what is model number of your fan. If you can, upload a picture.
[image: Stubby]

Comment: I did post a picture, click on the 'We just bought a house and it has this ceiling fan' link. I tried to post it inline, but that's how it did it. I think it's a Hampton Bay, but I'm not 100% sure. I can't get my head between the top and the ceiling to read the sticker. It looks like there's 5 access panels, each with 2 screws. I know I can do it with an offset screwdriver, but that is just crazy.

Comment: @Larry after looking at the picture and the your last post, you are going to have to take off the 2 screw per access panels but not all of them, just the ones next to the lamp.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Hampton Bay (Home Depot) model with an 'Up' light. With a step ladder and an appropriate length Phillips screwdriver it is really simple. There is a small cover over each bulb and you have to remove 2 screws to get it off and get at the bulb. There are 4 C7 type bulbs that are 15 watts with 100 Lumens.  Home Depot sells replacements as "Ceiling Fan" light bulbs. You can use C7 Christmas tree light bulbs but they would be very dim.

Comment: Thanks but this is a 5 year old post and I don’t own this house any more.

Comment: @LarryMartell It doesn't matter that this is an old question; others may benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

That fan should have a small plate with a single screw for each bulb. They are most likely 7 watt night light bulbs.

You can tilt the fan over a bit to easier access the screws, unless the fan is semi-flush rigidly mounted. And yes, a stubby screwdriver helps.

Answer (score 0):

I took off the blades first, then use Phillips stubby screwdriver to remove the screws (there are 3, be careful not to drop the clips the screws screw into), drop the shade, replace the bulbs with LEDs, then make sure the clips are aligned on the shade so the screws can find the hole.  So, carefully align them first then move the shade up and try to hand twist one screw into the clips, the clips move easily so try not to disturb their position.  Then put the blades back on and you're done.